# How to assign certain amount of rdms records to each thread for processing in java

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading

Here,I have created two threads.I'm trying to read the records from mysql in a batch and trying to assign that batch to each thread for writing those records to console.

Suppose I have two batches containing 10 records each.I'm trying to assign each batch to each thread for writing those records to console.

Here only thread1 is reading all the 1000 records(10 records per batch).But I'm to create thread2.How can I create thread2,so that it involves in parallel processing.

My code:

```
public class DataRead {

    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";

    static final String USER ="root";
    static final String PASS ="abc";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

        System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER,PASS);
        System.out.println("Connected to Database Successfully !!!");

        ResultSet rs = null;

        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        int maxRecords = 10;
        int initialcount =0;
        int count =0;
         rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer");
         rs.next();
         count = rs.getInt(1);
         System.out.println(count);

        for(int i=0;i<count/10;i++){

                String sql =" SELECT customerId,firstName,lastName FROM customer  ORDER BY customerId LIMIT "+initialcount+","+maxRecords;

                rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

                String CustID= null;
                String firstName = null;
                String lastName = null;


                ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
                List<CustomerData> list = new ArrayList<CustomerData>();

                while(rs.next()){

                    CustomerData customer = new CustomerData();
                    customer.setCustID(rs.getString("customerId"));
                    customer.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstName"));
                    customer.setLastName(rs.getString("lastName"));

                    list.add(customer);

                }
                MyRunnable task1 = new  MyRunnable(list);
                  threadExecutor.execute( task1 );


                threadExecutor.shutdown();
                while(!threadExecutor.isTerminated()){
                    try {
                        threadExecutor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                        }
                }

                initialcount = initialcount + maxRecords;
        }

    System.out.println("Finished all threads !!!");
    }

}
```

MyRunnable:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable{

    private  final List list;

    public MyRunnable(List list){
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
            CustomerData cust = (CustomerData) list.get(i);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+"Hello: "+cust.getCustID()+" "+cust.getFirstName()+" "+cust.getLastName());
        }


    }

}
```

CustomerData:

```
public class CustomerData {

       private String custID;
       private String firstName;
       private String lastName;

    public String getCustID() {
        return custID;
    }
    public void setCustID(String custID) {
        this.custID = custID;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick solution i used to follow often,

Have internal `concurrent queue`. Enqueue batch into it. Foreach thread dequeue the value(batch from internal queue) and assign it.

**NOT A COMPLETE SOLUTION**

Step1:

```
Queue<List<CustomerData>> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ArrayList<CustomerData>>();
```

Step2: foreach selected item create batch of objects ( say 10)

```
ArrayList<CustomerData> listofobjects = // insert batch of vales selected from DB
```

step3:

```
queue.add(listofobjects); // add your batches into concurrent queue
```

Step4:

```
while(queue.isEmpty()){
    ArrayList<CustomerData> batch = queue.poll();
    // Pass batch to Thread and print it.
}
```

Comment: @dev777, Here is the simple pseudo. give a try